# Reduction or with stride

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'd like to make an or of some bits, but they are not on a contiguous array. See `|ack[i-1:0][j]` in the following example, where `|` is the bitwise reduction `or`.

```vhd
module cb #(
    parameter PORTS = 4
)(
     input              dest[PORTS][PORTS],
     output             ack[PORTS][PORTS]
);

generate
genvar i, j, used[PORTS];
    for ( i = 0; i < PORTS; i++ )
    begin
        for ( j = 0; j < PORTS; j++) 
        begin
            assign ack[i][j] = dest[i][j] && ! (|ack[i-1:0][j]);
        end
    end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

> In this concrete case, what I really want is for the `ack[i][j]` bit to be 1 for the first `dest[i][j]` that is 1 in each "column".

Obviously, this gives a "range not allowed in a prefix" error. How could I implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an auxiliary signal, I guess this is what you tried to do with the genvar `used[PORTS]`, genvars are processed during compilation time so they can't hold values that depends on the inputs, this is why we must use a signal.

used[i][j] is will iteratively compute `ack[0][j] | ... | ack[i-1][j]`

```sv
module cb #(
    parameter PORTS = 4
)(
     input              dest[PORTS][PORTS],
     output             ack[PORTS][PORTS]
);
logic used[PORTS][PORTS];

generate
genvar i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < PORTS; i++ )
    begin
        for ( j = 0; j < PORTS; j++) 
        begin
            assign used[i][j] = i == 0 ? 1'b0: ack[i][j] | used[i-1][j];
            assign ack[i][j] = dest[i][j] && ! used[i-1][j];
        end
    end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: Why is `used` a 2D array?

Comment: Because it must hold the prefix or for each column.

Comment: I understand now, thanks! Btw, on line 16 I changed `used[i-1:0][j]` to `used[i-1][j]`, to avoid the "range not allowed in a prefix" error

Comment: Sorry, my mistake there, I hope you deem it acceptable accordingly to https://stackoverflow.com/tour, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generate block just cause creation of 16 separate assignments in your case. they do not make much sense here. There is a simpler solution with a single procedural block.

```
module cb #(
    parameter PORTS = 4
)(
     input          dest[PORTS][PORTS],
     output  logic  ack[PORTS][PORTS]
);

    always @* begin
      logic flag;
      flag = 0;
      for ( int i = 0; i < PORTS; i++ ) begin
        for ( int j = 0; j < PORTS; j++) begin
          if (dest[i][j] == 1'b1)
            flag = 1;
          ack[i][j] = flag;
        end
      end
    end
endmodule
```

You set `flag` when *dest* condition is right. It is persistent till the end of the block, setting value of *ack*. It works according to your description.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up combining both answers to get the following code:

```vhd
module cb #(
    parameter PORTS = 4
)(
     input              dest[PORTS][PORTS],
     output             ack[PORTS][PORTS]
);
logic used[PORTS][PORTS];

always_comb begin 
    logic used[PORTS];

    // First resetting to 0
    for ( int j = 0; j < PORTS; j++ )
        used[j] = 0;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < PORTS; i++ )
    begin
        for ( int j = 0; j < PORTS; j++)
        begin
            ack[i][j] = dest[i][j] && !used[j];
            used[j] = used[j] | ack[i][j];
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

This code takes into account that at most one port can be used “per column” (and not just one at all).